# Auto truncate WooCommerce Single Product Description with a read more functionality

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to truncate the long Product Description with a "read more"/"read less" toggle. I have three paragraphs of text in my description, and I want to truncate the description with a "...read more" link after the first or midway through the second sentence in the first paragraph.

I have tried the code below in my child theme functions.php file, but it only truncates the first paragraph, and still shows the remaining two paragraphs of text below it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_woo_prod_description' );

function custom_woo_prod_description() {
wc_enqueue_js('
var show_char = 400;
var ellipses = "… ";
var description_content = $(".woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description").html();
if (description_content.length > show_char) {
var a = description_content.substring(0, show_char);
var html = "" + a + ellipses + "Read more" + content + "Read less";
$(".woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description").html(html);
}
$(".read-more").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description .truncated").toggle();
});
$(".read-less").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description .truncated").toggle();
});
');
}
```

Can you suggest an edit so that is truncates the other paragraphs as well?

The code posted only truncates the first paragraph.

Comment: the code seems incomplete, variable `content` is not defined anywhere. code blindly replace innerHTML from `.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description` without respecting any html even breaking the structure. the value of variable `content` contains "pre-truncated" version at element with class `truncated`, the code responsible for that is not present in your question.

Answer (score 2):

To effectively truncate the product description with a "read more" / "read less" toggle, you can use the following revised code instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_woo_prod_description' );
function custom_woo_prod_description()
{
    $chars_length = 400; // Number of desired characters length
    $css_selector = '.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description'; // Targeted CSS selector

    // Read more or less buttons:
    $more_link    = sprintf( '… <a class="read-link" data-id="more">%s</a>', __('Read more', 'woocommerce') );
    $less_link    = sprintf( '<a class="read-link" data-id="less">%s</a>', __('Read less', 'woocommerce') );

    wc_enqueue_js( "const n = {$chars_length}, s = '{$css_selector}', d = $(s).html();

    function cleanTruncate(a, b){
        return a.substr(0, b + a.substr(b).indexOf(' '));
    }

    if (d.length > n) {
        const t = cleanTruncate(d, n), m = t+'{$more_link}', l = d+'{$less_link}';

        $(s).html(m);

        $(document.body).on('click', s+' .read', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ( $(this).data('id') === 'more' ) {
                $(s).html(l);
            } else {
                $(s).html(m);
            }
        });
    }" );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.